# Login php code, different content for admin/user:

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Can you please help me to figure out how shall I use this if statement to show different content to different type of users.

this is the code that I have already found on another question:

```
  if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 2){  //do stuff here}  if ($_SESSION['usertype']) == 1) { //do stuff here }
```

I want to use this on a page where only members can view the page, and depending on the usertype, it should show different content.

But I'm not able to send the usertype in the login page when a user logs in, this is the code used there (login.php):

```
<?php 

// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
require("common.php"); 

// This variable will be used to re-display the user's username to them in the 
// login form if they fail to enter the correct password.  It is initialized here 
// to an empty value, which will be shown if the user has not submitted the form. 
$submitted_username = ''; 

// This if statement checks to determine whether the login form has been submitted 
// If it has, then the login code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    // This query retreives the user's information from the database using 
    // their username. 
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            id, 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
            usertype
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 

    // The parameter values 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        // Execute the query against the database 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    // This variable tells us whether the user has successfully logged in or not. 
    // We initialize it to false, assuming they have not. 
    // If we determine that they have entered the right details, then we switch it to true. 
    $login_ok = false; 

    // Retrieve the user data from the database.  If $row is false, then the username 
    // they entered is not registered. 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row) 
    { 
        // Using the password submitted by the user and the salt stored in the database, 
        // we now check to see whether the passwords match by hashing the submitted password 
        // and comparing it to the hashed version already stored in the database. 
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
        } 

        if($check_password === $row['password']) 
        { 
            // If they do, then we flip this to true 
            $login_ok = true; 
        } 
    } 

    // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
    // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
    if($login_ok) 
    { 
        // Here I am preparing to store the $row array into the $_SESSION by 
        // removing the salt and password values from it.  Although $_SESSION is 
        // stored on the server-side, there is no reason to store sensitive values 
        // in it unless you have to.  Thus, it is best practice to remove these 
        // sensitive values first. 
        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']); 

        // This stores the user's data into the session at the index 'user'. 
        // We will check this index on the private members-only page to determine whether 
        // or not the user is logged in.  We can also use it to retrieve 
        // the user's details. 
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 
        $_SESSION['usertype'] = $row; 


        // Redirect the user to the private members-only page. 
     header("Location: dashboard.php"); 
      die("Redirecting to: dashboard.php"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // Tell the user they failed 
        print("Login Failed."); 

        // Show them their username again so all they have to do is enter a new
        // password.  The use of htmlentities prevents XSS attacks.  You should
        // always use htmlentities on user submitted values before displaying them
        // to any users (including the user that submitted them).  For more information:
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS_attack
        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
?>
```

What changes do I need to make in this code?
I am quite new to all this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you setting same variable twice to $_SESSION

Comment: why are you setting `user` and `usertype` to the same variable?

Comment: "$_SESSIONN['usertype'] = $row;" this is just me trying to figure out, what shall I use instead? thanks for the prompt response

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the last bit of your `if($login_ok)` section to set the `$_SESSION` variables correctly:

```
if($login_ok)
{
    ...
    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['usertype'] = $row['usertype'];
    ...
}
```

From what I can see in your code, if the rest of it works correctly then the `dashboard.php` page should be able to access it like this:

```
<?php
require("common.php");

if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 2) {
    //do stuff here
} elseif($_SESSION['usertype']) == 1) {
    //do stuff here
}
?>
```